# mvc publish error with automigrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems publishing my MVC project.

I got the error "The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).", that was solved with the help of automigrations.

I published my project via ftp on the another machine, then added some changes on the model`s structure, run it on my computer, it launced succesfull and published again on the same another machine. When I tryed to run it there, an error occurred - "The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)."

I'm using IIS7 on Windows 7.

Comment: if you change the model you must update your database with migration

Comment: How can I update a database located on the computer to which I am referring to ftp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update database on another Db server you could make this way:

1. Configure connection string to use new server
2. Run `Update-database` command from package manager console, in some cases you will need to use `-force` flag. But be careful this could delete some your data. Also this command has - ConnectionStringName parameter this could help you to make updates.

This is a very bad approach and I don't recommend update database this way.

I would recommend you set up Initialzier for your context. I usually  use `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` and after changing your model you will need to add new migration, using `Add-migration` command.

To set up it use this command in application start method:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You must update your database after changing the model. Another machine and your computer use the same database? If not you must update this database.

Comment: How can I update a database located on the computer to which I am referring to ftp? Can this happen automatically?

Comment: Migrations, especially auto-migrations are *for development only*. In production, you are responsible for performing whatever schema changes are necessary on your production database. That is by design, as it would be *extremely* ill-advised to have anything automatically changing your production schema.